# Sort dict by key when key is a version

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, python-3.x

I'm trying to print out a dictionary (actually a `defaultdict`) where the keys are version numbers (in the form `6.0` or `6.1.2`) and the values are floats.

```
# Parse file contents
firmware_percents = defaultdict(float)
with open('test.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)

    for row in reader:
        # Don't care about iphone vs ipad
        # Must be a string - StrictVersion is apparently unhashable
        rev = row["Firmware Version"].split(" ")[2]

        # Dump extra spaces, the less than (assume .1%), and % sign
        percent = float(row["% of Sessions"].strip().lstrip("<").strip("%"))
        firmware_percents[rev] += percent

def pretty_print(d):
    for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True):
        print("{0}: {1:.1f}".format(k, d[k]))

print("All versions:")
pretty_print(firmware_percents)
```

However, when I do this some versions are printing out of order:

```
All versions:
7.0: 44.2
7.0.2: 25.7
6.1.3: 14.2
6.1.4: 5.5
7.0.1: 3.2
6.1: 2.7
# You get the point
```

Using this input file:

```
Firmware Version,Sessions,% of Sessions
" iPhone 5.0.1 ",20," <0.1% "
" iPhone 6.0 ",26," 0.1% "
" iPhone 5.1.1 ",69," 0.3% "
" iPhone 5.1 ",2," <0.1% "
" iPhone 7.0 ",7401," 31.5% "
" iPhone 6.1 ",337," 1.4% "
" iPhone 6.1.3 ",2193," 9.3% "
" iPhone 6.1.2 ",84," 0.4% "
" iPhone 7.0.1 ",747," 3.2% "
" iPhone 7.0.2 ",4619," 19.7% "
" iPhone 6.0.1 ",37," 0.2% "
" iPhone 6.0.2 ",1," <0.1% "
" iPhone 6.1.4 ",1281," 5.5% "
" iPad 5.0 ",4," <0.1% "
" iPad 5.1 ",100," 0.4% "
" iPad 5.1.1 ",545," 2.3% "
" iPad 6.0 ",16," <0.1% "
" iPad 6.1 ",305," 1.3% "
" iPhone 7.0.3 ",1," <0.1% "
" iPhone 6.1.1 ",1," <0.1% "
" iPad 7.0 ",2979," 12.7% "
" iPad 6.0.1 ",100," 0.4% "
" iPad 6.1.3 ",1139," 4.9% "
" iPad 6.0.2 ",5," <0.1% "
" iPad 6.1.2 ",65," 0.3% "
" iPad 7.0.2 ",1404," 6.0% "
```

I've tried `pprint`, and while it does sort in the correct order it doesn't format the floats (so I end up with numbers like 14.5999999996). It also occasionally prints strangeness like `defaultdict(<class 'float'>, {'5': 3.3, '6': 24.2, '7': 73.2})` when I try to do major version only.

How can I ensure these print in version order with formatted percentages?

By order I mean it sorts by major then minor then build/super-minor (7.0.2 > 7.0.1 > 6.1.4 > 6.1 etc etc)?

Comment: It looks to me, like your sorting key calls `d.get` on the key, thus getting you the values as sorting keys. Thus, the sort actually ignores the keys and sorts by the values.

Comment: @dornhege Gah, I definitely was not intending to sort by the percentage. Now I feel quite silly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think @dornhege spotted the main issue first: `key=d.get` means that you're sorting by the values, not the keys.

I'd leverage the stdlib package `distutils` to get the version stuff handled automatically:

```
>>> sorted(firmware_percents, key=distutils.version.StrictVersion, reverse=True)
['7.0.3', '7.0.2', '7.0.1', '7.0', '6.1.4', '6.1.3', '6.1.2', '6.1.1', '6.1', '6.0.2', '6.0.1', '6.0', '5.1.1', '5.1', '5.0.1', '5.0']
>>> sorted(firmware_percents, key=distutils.version.LooseVersion, reverse=True)
['7.0.3', '7.0.2', '7.0.1', '7.0', '6.1.4', '6.1.3', '6.1.2', '6.1.1', '6.1', '6.0.2', '6.0.1', '6.0', '5.1.1', '5.1', '5.0.1', '5.0']
```

This has advantages over splitting by `.` because it'll be smarter about handling things like `7.0.2rc1`.

Comment: Need to add: `from distutils.version import LooseVersion, StrictVersion`

Answer (score 3):

Convert the version numbers to lists-of-integers for sorting:

```
def pretty_print(d):
    for k in sorted(d, key=lambda x: x.split("."), reverse=True):
        print("{0}: {1:.1f}".format(k, d[k]))
```

Using `operator.methodcaller` is probably a bit more efficient, though.

```
from operator import methodcaller
def pretty_print(d):
    for k in sorted(d, key=methodcaller('split', '.'), reverse=True):
        print("{0}: {1:.1f}".format(k, d[k]))
```

Comment: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil"  - There is not much  point on gaining even 20% processing speed in something that will be done but once each time the process is run, at the cost of having to learn, and  "fit" methodcaller semantics in one's mind?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, dictionaries are not sortable - and your recipe, which uses the dictionary's "get" method as  sorting key is sorting by the dictionairies values - not by the keys.

So, when you call `for k in sorted(d, key=d.get, reverse=True)`
what happens is that each key in the dictionary, is passed to the dictionairy's "get" method - that retrieve the values instead.

If you want to sort by the key there is no need to pass any value to "key" at all. Just do:
`for k in sorted(d,  reverse=True):`

However, versions like "10.1" will come first than "2.0" since it is a string comparison - 
spliting the version number at the "."s and converting each part to a number will yield a correct comparison instead:

`for k in sorted(d, key=lambda x: tuple(int(n) for n in x.split(".")) , reverse=True):`

Comment: answer is outdated

Comment: sorry - but did you just voted the answer down because it is "outdated"? btw, it is not. Python dictionaries are now  _sorted_ by insertion order by default, but they are not "sortable", if that is the phrase you had a problem with - one needs to use some strategies to have a dictionary sorted by other criteria (like the version number in this case)

Comment: I don't understand your point. Since 3.7 dictionaries preserve order and, imo, are sortable

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to sort a list of strings, but not in lexicographical order. Instead you want it sorted as if each string is split into tuples of integers, and possibly other things like hyphens and spaces.

You can do something like

```py
#!/bin/python3

import re
import json

d = {
    "7.0":            "44.2",
    "7.0.20":         "25.7",
    "7.0.20-bbb":  "25.7",
    "7.0.20-aaa":  "25.7",
    "7.0.2":          "25.7",
    "7.0.3":          "25.7",
    "6.1.3":          "14.2",
    "6.1.4":          "5.5",
    "7.0.1":          "3.2",
    "6.1":            "2.7"
}

def sort(kv):
    return tuple((
        int(v) if v.isdigit() else v
        for v in re.split('[.-]', kv[0])
        ))

d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=sort))

print(json.dumps(d, indent=2))
```